# Как отключить автообновление браузера в Angular 6 CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Есть проект на Ангуляре CLI. Дело в том, что сейчас работаю на компьютере с недостаточной производительностью. Поэтому автообновление браузера после изменения каждого символа занимает сейчас много времени.
Как это отключить?

PS: работаю в Webstorm, если что.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть опция `live-reload`, когда вы запускаете команду `serve` - просто установите значение этого параметра `false`:

```
ng s --live-reload=false
```

`s` - алиас для `serve`.